# Task Scheduler and Workbook Open macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that does different things depending on the time it was opened.
I am using task scheduler to open the file. The code runs the part before the second `elseif` runs no problem. 
However the second `elseif` will not run when the file is opened from task scheduler.

```
Sub workbook_open()

Dim time_now As String

time_now = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

If time_now > "00:05:00" And time_now < "00:05:30" And ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
ElseIf time_now > "00:05:00" And time_now < "00:05:30" And ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing = False Then
Application.Quit
ElseIf time_now > "00:10:00" And time_now < "00:11:00" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call Sheet2.Update
    If Not ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, accessmode:=xlShared
End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
Else

End If

End Sub
```

If i run the code manually with F8, there is no problem. Also sheet2.update works no problem.

Not quite sure why if anyone can give pointers. 
Thanks!

Comment: Do a time comparison using `TimeSerial()`

Comment: Seems like you missed my comment. I meant something like this `If Now > TimeSerial(5, 0, 0) And Now < TimeSerial(5, 30, 0) And ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then` Change this for the `ElseIf` as well

Comment: doesnt work for some reason. But heres an update, if i open it by hand. everything works... if task scheduler opens it, only the first if statement runs..

Comment: please update the code that you are using now

Comment: no luck =(. and trust settings should be ok since the first if statement is properly executed. just not the elseifs and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your macro trust settings are blocking the case when the file is opened by the task scheduler.

Comment: but why does the first and second if/elseif statements work if thats the case?